# Blazor initialize a date on page load

Tags: c#, blazor

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
    <span class="label-input100">Date of Birth</span>
    <InputDate class="input100" id="birthday" name="birthday" @bind-Value="CurrentCustomerSubmission.DateOfBirth" max="@DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year-60,1,1).ToString()" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => CurrentCustomerSubmission.DateOfBirth)" />
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is have the initial value of the date to be

1/1/(current year - 60)

I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Where are you initializing `CurrentCustomerSubmission`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer DateTimeOffset over DateTime but the idea is still the same:

```
override protected void OnInitialized() // Where ever you are initialising your CurrentCustomer Submission
{
    CurrentCustomerSubmission = new Customer();
    CurrentCustomerSubmission.DateOfBirth =  new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 60, 1, 1);
}
```